# Python MySQLdb insert into primary key

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to use `mysqldb` to insert into a table and cast the auto increment value?

for example:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.v3_host, self.v3_user, self.v3_password, self.v3_database)
  self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def insert(self, query):
  try:
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    self.connection.commit()
  except:
    self.connection.rollback()
```

---

```
db3 = DatabaseV3()
insert = """INSERT INTO user_avatars (id, user_id, file_id) VALUES (..."""
db3.insert(insert)
```

`ID` is an auto-increment value from the database, but what if I wanted it to force insert a specific value for the column without actually altering the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because its auto incremented, doesn't mean you cannot override the value:

```
INSERT INTO user_avatars (id, user_id, file_id) VALUES (23, 42, 56)
```

You just have to make sure the value isn't being used, otherwise you'll get an exception from the database:

```
mysql> create table foo (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, bar INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (12,1), (23,1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;

+----+------+
| id | bar  |
+----+------+
| 12 |    1 |
| 23 |    1 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (bar) values (13);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| id | bar  |
+----+------+
| 12 |    1 |
| 23 |    1 |
| 24 |   13 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> insert into foo values (12, 2);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '12' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

You can also change the primary key's value if you like:

```
mysql> update foo set id = 13 where id = 12 limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| id | bar  |
+----+------+
| 13 |    1 |
| 23 |    1 |
| 24 |   13 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: the destination table is empty.

Comment: So? It was empty in my example.